# pandas to sql raise mysql raise errorclass(errno, errval)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I have large text (70000 row *100 columns) file to import into mysql database. the raw file is csv and very dirty. I use pandas to read that as str. however, when I import to mysql. I get following error.

> File "", line 1, in 
> runfile('E:/Python_Project/Candidate_Resume_date/candidate_resume_import_v3.py',
> wdir='E:/Python_Project/Candidate_Resume_date')
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
> line 705, in runfile
> execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
> line 102, in execfile
> exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File
> "E:/Python_Project/Candidate_Resume_date/candidate_resume_import_v3.py",
> line 164, in 
> dtype={col_name:LONGTEXT for col_name in candidate})
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 2127, in to_sql
> dtype=dtype)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line
> 450, in to_sql
> chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line
> 1149, in to_sql
> table.insert(chunksize)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line
> 663, in insert
> self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line
> 638, in _execute_insert
> conn.execute(*self.insert_statement(data, conn))
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 948, in execute
> return meth(self, multiparams, params)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py",
> line 269, in _execute_on_connection
> return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement
> compiled_sql, distilled_params
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1200, in _execute_context
> context)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception
> exc_info
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py",
> line 203, in raise_from_cause
> reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py",
> line 186, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1193, in _execute_context
> context)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
> line 507, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line
> 170, in execute
> result = self._query(query)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line
> 328, in _query
> conn.query(q)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> line 517, in query
> self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> line 732, in _read_query_result
> result.read()
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> line 1075, in read
> first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py",
> line 684, in _read_packet
> packet.check_error()
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py",
> line 220, in check_error
> err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
>
> File "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line
> 109, in raise_mysql_exception
> raise errorclass(errno, errval)
>
> (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value:
> '\xF0\x9F\x93\x8D: ...' for column 'All_Parsed_Resume_Text' at row
> 39")

after looking at the code, it seem like utf-8/unicode thing.

```
def raise_mysql_exception(data):
    errno = struct.unpack('<h', data[1:3])[0]
    is_41 = data[3:4] == b"#"
    if is_41:
        # client protocol 4.1
        errval = data[9:].decode('utf-8', 'replace')
    else:
        errval = data[3:].decode('utf-8', 'replace')
    errorclass = error_map.get(errno, InternalError)
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
```

however, I am not sure how to fix that.
I already mentioned following when i create the engine

```
db_connection_str = f'mysql+pymysql://{DB_BIDW_USER}:{DB_BIDW_PASSWORD}@{DB_BIDW_SERVER}/BI_HR?charset=utf8mb4'
candidate.to_sql('candidate_archive', sql_engine, schema= 'BI_HR', if_exists='replace', chunksize =100,
                         index=False, index_label=None, 
                         dtype={col_name:LONGTEXT for col_name in candidate})
```

and I could not locate the error based on the message, which is another thing I do not understand.

```
candidate.iloc[39]['All_Parsed_Resume_Text']
Out[6]: nan
```

pandas read data not show any error.

(I tried to load the data from excel power query then read excel from pandas and to sql. it works. however, It is not solution for me since I need to automate the process).

really appreciate if someone could provide any hint.

Comment: Please try with `encoding='latin'` especially if it has latin characters. A very precise answers requires you to show the sample data that's producing the error.